# Cross-domain policy not taking effect

Tags: silverlight, web-services, configuration, cross-domain

I've created a ClientAccessPolicy.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and put it in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\intranet-80 and then run an iisreset. Still, when I access the webservices through Silverlight, I get a CommunicationException saying that a correct cross-domain policy isn't in place. What more do I need to do to be able to access my webservices? I cannot access it from another host, and I cannot access it from the generated file E:\Development\MySLProject\ MySLProject\bin\Debug\Default.html?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to tell you *how* to troubleshoot this problem than tell you *where* exactly you have to put the file:

- Step 1: install and start [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2)
- Step 2: open your silverlight client
- Step 3: watch in Fiddler where your client is requesting clientAccessPolicy.xml (it's a simple http GET request, like downloading an image or whatever)
- Step 4: put your clientAccessPolicy file in the correct place (test by downloading it directly with your browser)

I bet you'll solve the problem in less than 10 minutes (been there, done that :-) )

Answer (score 3):

You have to put this file in the **server root**, not in your virtual directory root.

Comment: Hi Tucod, thank's a lot for your answer. I'm a bit confused, this is the root of the web site instance, and the configuration is regarding that instance.Where do I find the server root, and how should I modify my cross-domain-policy to only go with the desired web site, i.e. intranet-80? Cheers -Nik

Comment: If your web application is running at http://yourdomain/yourapp/default.aspx the server root is http://yourdomain/ so maybe it is something like c:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Comment: You mentioned your test URL was
 http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
so you should also be able to load
 http://sharepoint/ClientAccessPolicy.xml
- if both those links work from your web browser they should work in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I had a similar problem with the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and nothing I did to the file would get my Silverlight app to accept it and proceed onto calling the web services. I was using [ProxyTrace](http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/pt.aspx) to make sure the file was being requested by Silverlight and returned correctly which it was.

Eventually out of desperation I removed the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and tried the alternative crossdomain.xml file which is meant to be for Silverlight to work with Flash targetted web sites and that worked straight away.

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight: use a relative path in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file

```
<client>
<endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It's took 4 hours to resolve the issue. Initially I was putting "clientaccesspolicy.xml" and crossdomain into web service root. Once I put these files into server root C:\Inetpub\wwwroot" My applicatio has been started working.

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution is >> findout root physical path for your site >> copy the file "ClientAccessPolicy.xml" into it >> Now try to access.**